# JavaFX 2.2 not being detected automatically in eclipse on ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, javafx-2

I am on ubuntu 11.04. I have installed Jave jdk 7u7 recently which has javafx 2.2 bundled with it. I also have eclipse 3.7.2 installed.

Now I have an application source code which is built using ant. When I create a new project with this code, I get a build error for all uses of javafx. So, how do I get javafx working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it working, I had to add the external jar in properties -> java build path -> libraries(tab) -> add external jars.

The jar can be found in < jdk-location >/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar

Hence, for me, it was at /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar

Comment: This is scheduled to be fixed in a future jdk/jre release, the related bug to track is [7166330: Need to add jfxrt.jar to the boot classpath for 7u6 true cobundle](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7166330)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [e(fx)clipse](http://efxclipse.org/) plugin which ([in version 0.1.0 and later](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2012/07/20/efxclipse-0-1-0-released/)) will take care of the the issues of finding a relevant JavaFX install.